# Print registration and login forms on same page

Tags: 7, forms, users

How do I print the register and login forms on the same page?

I think I am really looking just for the form IDs, but if you've got the right render function handy it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form')));
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login_block')));
```

See [user_register_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_register_form/7) and [user_login_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_block/7) for details. Note that `user_register_form` is an unusual form builder function: it redirects in some cases.

Comment: Beautiful mate. Perfect answer!

Comment: Any idea how to get this in Drupal 8? Thanks.

Comment: Phil, maybe this is of any help: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder%3A%3AgetForm/8

Answer (score 6):

I took the code from LoginToboggan. This is what I got.

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_theme()
*/
function os_pages_theme() {
  return array(
    'os_pages_login_form' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'register_form' => NULL,
        'login_form' => NULL,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
/**
* Logintobbogin provides the code to consolidate
* the registration page and the login page however
* it doesn't do exactly the way we want so we will 
* take the code. 
* @see http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan
*/

 /**
 * Implementation of hook_menu_alter().
 */
function os_pages_menu_alter(&$callbacks) {
  // Kill the tabs on the login pages.
  $callbacks['user/login']['type'] = MENU_NORMAL_ITEM;
  $callbacks['user/login']['page callback'] = 'os_pages_login_page';
  $callbacks['user/register']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
  $callbacks['user/register']['page callback'] = 'os_pages_login_page';
  $callbacks['user/register']['page arguments'] = array('register');
  $callbacks['user/password']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
  $callbacks['user']['page callback'] = 'os_pages_login_page';
}
/**
 * Menu callback for user/login
 *   creates a unified login/registration form (without tabs)
 */
function os_pages_login_page() {
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid) {
    menu_set_active_item('user/' . $user->uid);
    return menu_execute_active_handler(NULL, FALSE);
  }
  else {
    // Title just clutters the interface...
    drupal_set_title('');
    $output = os_pages_login_form();
    return $output;
  }
}
/**
 * Builds a unified login form.
 */
function os_pages_login_form() {
  $register_form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
  $login_form = drupal_get_form('user_login');
  $rendered_register_form = drupal_render($register_form);
  $rendered_login_form = drupal_render($login_form);
  $variables = array(
    'login_form' => $rendered_login_form,
    'register_form' => $rendered_register_form,
  );
  $output = theme('os_pages_login_form', $variables);
  return $output;
}
/**
 * Theme function for unified login page.
 */
function theme_os_pages_login_form($variables) {

  $register_form = $variables['register_form'];
  $login_form = $variables['login_form'];
  $output = '';

  $output .= '<div class="login-form">';

  // Add the login and registration forms in.
  $output .= '<div id="register-form">' . $register_form . '</div>';
  $output .= '<div id="login-form">' . $login_form . '</div>';

  $output .= '</div>';

  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) do this for you: Install it, and go to admin/config/system/logintoboggan; select "Present a unified login/registration page."

Comment: also if you want write your own module, you can look at its source

Answer (score 4):

For this 
You need to create a page for Registration like this

```
page-user-register.tpl.php
```

And print the page contents as usual. 
in that page you could try render `user_login_block`

Additional resources

1. http://www.trevorsimonton.com/blog/page-usertplphp-profile-php-template-drupal
2. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_block/7

Comment: The chosen answer http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/27419/4471  Will throw validation error.