# Login and registration form in a single page

Tags: 7, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print registration and login forms on same page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27416/print-registration-and-login-forms-on-same-page)

I found the [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module, but it doesn't allow to register and log in from the same page.

What should I do to get registration and login form in the same page?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered many times here.
See this [Print registration and login forms on same page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27416/print-registration-and-login-forms-on-same-page/27418#27418)

For this You need to create a page for Registration like this

```
page-user-register.tpl.php
```

And print the page contents as usual. 
in that page you could try render `user_login_block`

Additional resources

1. http://www.trevorsimonton.com/blog/page-usertplphp-profile-php-template-drupal
2. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_block/7