# How to show a user login form on a completely separate page?

Tags: 7, forms, users

I am developing a application where I want to restrict everything from anonymous users. If anyone tries to access any page from url directly they will be redirected to login page. How to do this?

Also I want show the login page in a completely separate page where there should be no menu or any other links, just the login form (like for example: google login page). What is the best way to do this.

Comment: Would be more helpful if you told us your Drupal version (-_-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lynbermt suggests, you can easily remove permission to do anything at all from the anonymous user at `admin/people/permissions`. There are a few other great add-ons to this:

- Create a 403 page in the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module and add a login form, making it visible only to anonymous users
- Activate the login block at `admin/structure/block` so that it's always visible to anonymous users no matter what page they're on
- Remove anything else from the main page, or make everything invisible to anonymous users (panels panes, blocks, etc.)

It will basically just take a lot of testing, browsing around as an anonymous user to see what's visible and then go hide it. And beware! Every time you add a new module or bit of functionality you should re-test as much of it as possible to make sure that an anonymous user can't get at anything. Vigilance. Each module will have its own new permissions to configure, security risks to watch out for, etc.

Comment: I accept the first part, but is it possible without using Panels or any other module with a simple theme hook

Comment: Well, drupal 7 comes with blocks...so that one could do it, no?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to remove all permissions from the anonymous user at /admin/people/permissions and then set the 403 page on /admin/config/system/site-information to /user.

Answer (score 0):

> If anyone tries to access any page from url directly they will be redirected to login page.

Create a rule using the [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module, which looks like so:

- **Event:** Drupal is initializing
- **Conditions:**

  1. *User has role(s)* - `Parameter: User: [site:current-user], Roles: anonymous user`
  2. *NOT Text comparison* - `Parameter: Text: [site:current-page:url], Matching text: user/login`
- **Actions:** *Page redirect* - `Parameter: URL: user/login`

> ... login page in a completely separate page where there should be no menu or any other links.

For any blocks shown on the login page (eg related to menu blocks for primary menu, navigation menu, etc), set the block visibility settings so that these blocks are not shown for anonymous users.

Comment: Your answar is good, but  I don't want to use any extra module(Rules). Is it possible  with a theme hook  function or may be using a .tpl file? 

 I think as lynbermt suggested "remove permission to do anything at all from the anonymous user" is a good choice to restrict anonymous  user accessing pages.

Comment: @NabajitRoy : There are multiple ways to implement what you asked about. Using a theme hook or .tpl file is probably another approach. However "IMO" it is not a good practice to include "logic" in a theme (if you change themes it's gone ...). Moreover, the answer from lynbermt  appears to be incomplete (if you don't do anything else, then I think the 2nd parg of your question is not addressed (or am I missing something about that)? PS: is this question about D7 or D8?

Comment: Hi Pierre, Thanks for you replay.  I am using D7 for my project. 

By the way I got the following url, Can you suggest me is that a correct way to do this 

Link  - https://www.drupal.org/node/350634

Answer (score 0):

> If anyone tries to access any page from url directly they will be
>   redirected to login page.

You could use:

#### [Require Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/require_login)

> Require user authentication (login) on all pages, regardless of user
>   role permission settings.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Ability to make all pages require user login.
> - Easily exclude paths from requiring user login.
> - Customize require login user message.

---

> Also I want show the login page in a completely separate page where
>   there should be no menu or any other links

You can create a custom module with a custom path Ex: `/login` use [Drupal render login form programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995551/drupal-render-login-form-programatically) or [Print registration and login forms on same page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27416/print-registration-and-login-forms-on-same-page) to display the form.

Make a copy of page.tpl.php and rename the copy to Ex: page--login.tpl.php. Edit the file and delete the print menu part.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for all your suggestions. I find the answer after doing some google.

1) restrict everything from anonymous users.

I added the following code in my custom module init hook

```
function mymodule_init(){
$login_path =  'user/login';
if (user_is_anonymous() && current_path() != $login_path) {
  $path = $_GET['destination'];
  $destination = array('destination' => $path);
  header('Location: ' . url($login_path, array('query' => $destination, 'absolute' => TRUE)), TRUE);
 drupal_exit();
 }
}
```

2) show the login page in a completely separate page

For this I added "page--user--login.tpl.php" in my theme folder and rendered the login form with the following code-

```
<?php
 print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login_block')));
?>
```

Thats it. Any more suggestion greatly appreciated.